# Create Environment with Libraries in Eclipse C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, fedora, lib, libffi

I'am code a program that needs a newer version of a lib. However, Fedora 16 doesn't support this new version installation package (libffi 3.1). Can I create an environment  for Eclipse with the path of .so to run this lib only in my program?

Comment: It might be faster, and simpler, to install the current version of Fedora? That one is, what, ten years old?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Indeed. But i'am working in a comercial product that runs in this version, so update fedora sadly it's not a option

Comment: A "commercial product" that's based on Fedora? Doesn't sound like a commercial product that anyone should be using, in the first place. I suppose that placing the shared library somewhere, manually setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and then manually launching eclipse is worth a shot. If the "new version of a lib" carries a new soname, this is unlikely to work.